# Is there a way to have a full site button on a mobile app without javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I currently an redirecting to a mobile site based through htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Is there someway to have a full site button on my mobile version that will ignore this rule if clicked? I don't want to use javascript to do my redirect and check for full site...I'm okay with the idea of php doing it though, but I know htaccess gets knocked off before php rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a button/href link with this URL:

```
<a href="/?desktop=1">Full Desktop Site</a>
```

And then change your rewrite as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)desktop=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Do you know of any other ways to go about it with this approach or is this the common practice used?

Comment: This is the most common practice followed on many websites these days. Some of them use anchors also like `domain.com/#desktop` but idea is same.

Comment: Alright thanks. I think you helped me on pros vs cons in using vhosts vs a redirect for mobile...They still want to use a redirect sadly. I wish I have concrete evidence on why its bad.

Comment: What would the anchor alternative to this look like? Surely its not QUERY_STRING right?

Comment: Problem with anchors is that mod_rewrite won't work and you need to handle this in Javascript itself since part after `#` doesn't come to web server